# C# won't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, compiler-errors, publish

I am trying to publish a simple c# script, however it fails each time.

The program will sucessfully build each time but fails when publishing. I have tried with many different scripts, even the default Hello world and each time I get the same error.

```
2>The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Parzavil\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.win-x86\3.1.17\runtimes\win-x86\lib\netcoreapp3.1\System.Windows.Extensions.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have restarting my PC and only launching VS but it is still being used. Could this be caused by my AV as I am using a company managed CarbonBlack AV, or is it something to do with my VS installation?

Comment: If the @guustysebie's solution does not work, you can safelly delete the .nuget folder that is a cache for download optimization, as I understood. If you can't do that, try to use a software like https://lockhunter.com or search the web for direct hack by hand using the console.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem with your nuget packages.

You can try reinstalling them.

```
nuget locals all -list
nuget locals all -clear
```